# Any built-in Matlab function to find if a certain number lies between two members of a vector?

Tags: matlab, time-complexity

It should return lowest index i if a number a lies between x(i) and x(i+1). I know it's not hard to write a function which would do this but is there any built-in Matlab function for this?

Assuming the vector elements are sorted it would be a trivial search O(logn) I guess but is there any better way to do it if the elements are not sorted without going through sorting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But what should it do in the case where there is more than one particular value of i in which this condition holds?

Comment: I think your requirements are still not quite clear enough.  If the vector to be searched is `[6,2,6,2,6,2]` and the number in question is  `4` what should the function you seek return ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logical indices are well suited for these kind of comparisons:

```
x = [6 2 6 7 3 5];
a = 4;
find(a > x(1:end-1) & a < x(2:end), 1)
ans =  2
```

Comment: Pretty elegant. Didn't know logical indexing till now, had entirely missed out a powerful tool of Matlab. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  a=rand(1);
  b=rand(1,10);
  c=a-b;
  find(c(2:end).*c(1:end-1)<0,1)
```